# SVG used as image is blury on iphone

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I am using an SVG based 64 as an image source.

This looks fine on a desktop, but when I view on my mobile (Iphone XS MAX - Safari), this looks really blury.

See below fiddle which has two images, one is just the raw SVG, and the second is the SVG base 64 used as source.

https://jsfiddle.net/t0e4sjw3/

You can see from the screenshot below, that the one used as an image is very blury and the filter seems to be a lot bigger than on the first image.

[image]

Is there any way to stop this?

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      version="1.1"
      width="110"
      height="110"
    >
      <defs>
        <filter id="dropShadow">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="1" />
          <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur" />
          <feFlood flood-color="black" />
          <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in" />
          <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          </feMerge>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <image
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="110"
        height="110"
        filter="url(#dropShadow)"
        preserveAspectRatio="none"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI2NCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI2NCI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI0VEQkE2RiIgZD0iTTU0Ljk1NSAxOC4yMTZjLjIxNi0yLjU3MiA4LjQ0Ni0xLjg0IDQuNDYzLTEuMTQzLTMuMjY3LjU3Mi00LjY3MiAzLjYyLTQuNDYzIDEuMTQzek00OS4yMTIgMjEuNDMyYzUuMTctMS4zNjcgMS40MDgtMjMuODg2IDEuMDkzLTEyLjY3OC0uMjYgOS4yMDItNi4wNjggMTMuOTk1LTEuMDkzIDEyLjY3OHoiLz48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImEiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMjQuMzY1IiB5MT0iMjEuODk5IiB4Mj0iMzguMjk2IiB5Mj0iNjMuNDA3Ij48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9Ii4yNDgiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlZGJhNmYiLz48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9Ii40OSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ViYjg2ZCIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iLjYzIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjZTJiMTY3Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuNzQ1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjZDRhNDVkIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuODQ1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjYzA5MzRmIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuOTM1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjYTc3YzNjIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjOGY2NzJiIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2EpIiBkPSJNMiA2MS43OXMyNi41NjMuODU5IDM1LjYwMy0uOWMxNy4wNjQtMy4zMiAxMy42MTktMzAuNjI5IDE3LjQxOS0zNC45NTMgNS4wMDEuMjA2IDYuNTAxLTguMzAyIDEuMTQ5LTguODc2LTQuNjgzLS41MDMtNy4xNTEtMy4wNjctOS42MzUgMi45OTJDMjguNTkxIDYzLjg0NSA0LjQyNSA1Ni42MDggMiA2MS43OXoiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjRURCQTZGIiBkPSJNNTYuNTgxIDE5LjU3OGMxLjUzMy0yLjk5MiA3Ljk3NCAzLjQwOCA0LjMwNSAxLjU5My0zLjAxMy0xLjQ4OC01Ljc4MiAxLjI4Ny00LjMwNS0xLjU5M3oiLz48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImIiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMi44OCIgeTE9IjQ3LjIyNyIgeDI9IjIxLjY1MSIgeTI9IjQ3LjIyNyI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjOTE2OTU4Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuNjY1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNWU0MDMzIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNGEyZjI0Ii8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2IpIiBkPSJNMi44OCA0NS42NDdjMi43ODQtMjAuMTIyIDIxLjYyOC01LjM3NSAxOC40IDguNzctMy4wNjcgNi45NTUtMTQuNTc5IDYuMTY2LTE4LjQtOC43N3oiLz48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImMiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMi44OCIgeTE9IjQ4LjE1MiIgeDI9IjEwLjg3MSIgeTI9IjQ4LjE1MiI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjOTE2OTU4Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuNjY1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNWU0MDMzIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNGEyZjI0Ii8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2MpIiBkPSJNMi44OCA0Ni42OTRjMS4wMDItMTAuNTM4IDkuODk1LTEuMDkgNy42MiA1Ljc5OS0xLjIxNSAzLjY4MS03LjMzNCAxLjg1Ni03LjYyLTUuNzk5eiIvPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZCIgZ3JhZGllbnRVbml0cz0idXNlclNwYWNlT25Vc2UiIHgxPSIyLjMyNSIgeTE9IjQ3LjU0IiB4Mj0iNi41MjYiIHkyPSI0Ny41NCI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjOTE2OTU4Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuNjY1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNWU0MDMzIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNGEyZjI0Ii8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2QpIiBkPSJNMi4zMjUgNDYuNzczYy41MjYtNS41NDIgNS4yMDMtLjU3MyA0LjAwNyAzLjA1LS42NCAxLjkzNi0zLjg1OC45NzYtNC4wMDctMy4wNXoiLz48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImUiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMi4zMjUiIHkxPSI0OC4wMjUiIHgyPSI0LjMzNyIgeTI9IjQ4LjAyNSI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjOTE2OTU4Ii8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIuNjY1IiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNWU0MDMzIi8+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSIjNGEyZjI0Ii8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2UpIiBkPSJNMi4zMzMgNDcuMjI0Yy4wMzUtLjg5MiAyLjI0Ni0uMzgzIDEuOTgyLjkxNi0uMDcuMzQ1LTIuMTMgMi44NDktMS45ODItLjkxNnoiLz48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9ImYiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iNC45MjgiIHkxPSI0MC43OTEiIHgyPSIzOC40NDciIHkyPSI0MC43OTEiPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMCIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzkxNjk1OCIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iLjY2NSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzVlNDAzMyIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzRhMmYyNCIvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0idXJsKCNmKSIgZD0iTTQuOTI4IDM5LjExMmM2LjU3My0xOS4zMzcgMjMuOTU2LTEzLjk1MiAzMS40MjUtMy44OTUgMCAwIDEuNzE5LS41NzYgMS45OTUuOTc4IDEuNDkyIDguMzg2LTE0LjMzMiAxNS42MzItMTcuNjE5IDE5LjI1MSAxLjU5Mi05LjU5NS03LjE5MS0yNS4xNzctMTUuODAxLTE2LjMzNHoiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjRURCQTZGIiBkPSJNNDguODU5IDE5Ljk3NmM0Ljc1OS0yLjc0MS0zLjMzLTIzLjYyLTEuNDMzLTEyLjYzMSAxLjU1NyA5LjAyMy0zLjE0OCAxNS4yNyAxLjQzMyAxMi42MzF6Ii8+PHBhdGggb3BhY2l0eT0iLjMiIGZpbGw9IiNBMzVEMzUiIGQ9Ik0yMy4xMjYgNTcuMDM2Yy4zMDkgMi4yNDQgMy4zMzYgMS44MzggMy4wMjUtLjQwOC0uMzEzLTIuMjk3LTMuMzM5LTEuODkxLTMuMDI1LjQwOHpNMzMuODM2IDUxLjgxM2MuMzA5IDIuMjQ1IDMuMzM2IDEuODM4IDMuMDI1LS40MDgtLjMxMy0yLjI5OC0zLjM0LTEuODkxLTMuMDI1LjQwOHpNMzUuNTYgNDYuNjExYy4yMTEgMS41MyAyLjI3NSAxLjI1MyAyLjA2NC0uMjc3LS4yMTQtMS41NjYtMi4yNzgtMS4yODktMi4wNjQuMjc3ek0zOS43MTUgNDMuMTQ3Yy4yMDkgMS41MjkgMi4yNzQgMS4yNTIgMi4wNjQtLjI3OS0uMjE1LTEuNTY2LTIuMjc4LTEuMjg5LTIuMDY0LjI3OXpNMzkuNzE2IDQ5LjgwMmMuMjA5IDEuNTMxIDIuMjcyIDEuMjU1IDIuMDYzLS4yNzctLjIxNS0xLjU2Ny0yLjI3OC0xLjI5LTIuMDYzLjI3N3pNMjkuMjc3IDUyLjc0NWMuMjEgMS41MjkgMi4yNzQgMS4yNTQgMi4wNjItLjI3OC0uMjEzLTEuNTY3LTIuMjc1LTEuMjg4LTIuMDYyLjI3OHpNMzAuOTk2IDU3LjI1N2MuMjA5IDEuNTI5IDIuMjczIDEuMjU0IDIuMDYyLS4yNzgtLjIxMy0xLjU2OC0yLjI3Ni0xLjI4OS0yLjA2Mi4yNzh6Ii8+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iI0VEQkE2RiIgZD0iTTQ3LjM4MiA1Ljk5N2MtMS42MDcgMC0xLjYwNy0zLjk5NyAwLTMuOTk3IDEuNjA5IDAgMS42MDkgMy45OTcgMCAzLjk5N3oiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjMzAyQzNCIiBkPSJNNDcuMzgyIDUuNDQ4Yy0xLjE2NiAwLTEuMTY2LTIuOSAwLTIuOSAxLjE2NyAwIDEuMTY3IDIuOSAwIDIuOXoiLz48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjNkU4MTg5IiBkPSJNNDcuMzgzIDMuNTY3YzAgLjUwNC0uNjI2LjUwNC0uNjI2IDAgMC0uNTA2LjYyNi0uNTA2LjYyNiAweiIvPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNFREJBNkYiIGQ9Ik01MC45MDIgNy4xODNjLTEuNjA4IDAtMS42MDgtMy45OTYgMC0zLjk5NiAxLjYxIDAgMS42MSAzLjk5NiAwIDMuOTk2eiIvPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiMzMDJDM0IiIGQ9Ik01MC45MDIgNi42MzVjLTEuMTY2IDAtMS4xNjYtMi45IDAtMi45IDEuMTY3IDAgMS4xNjcgMi45IDAgMi45eiIvPjxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiM2RTgxODkiIGQ9Ik01MC45MDMgNC43NTNjMCAuNTA0LS42MjYuNTA0LS42MjYgMCAwLS41MDYuNjI2LS41MDYuNjI2IDB6Ii8+PHBhdGggb3BhY2l0eT0iLjMiIGZpbGw9IiMyOTFFMUUiIGQ9Ik0zMS42NDEgMzEuOTI0YzEuNDI4LjQ2OC03Ljk0OCAxLjIzNy0xMi42NDMgOS40ODMgMS40MzktNi40NjYgOS40MDktMTAuNTQ2IDEyLjY0My05LjQ4M3pNOC44MzcgMzcuMjIxYy41MzUuMDUtMi4zMTQgMS4xNDUtMi4zOTIgNC42MDMtLjY1My0yLjUxOCAxLjE4MS00LjcxNyAyLjM5Mi00LjYwM3pNMTMuOTQ1IDM4LjMyMWMuNjcxLjAyOC0zLjQyOCAxLjQ0My00Ljg2MSA1LjQzNi4xMjgtMi44NjkgMy4zNDMtNS41MDIgNC44NjEtNS40MzZ6TTE4LjkxMSA0NS40ODVjLjY0Ni4zODEtNC4yNDctLjU4Ni04LjAzOSAyLjA2NCAxLjgzMy0yLjM4MiA2LjU3OS0yLjkyNSA4LjAzOS0yLjA2NHpNOC45OTQgNDQuNzUzYy4yODEuMTI5LTEuNjM1LjA4Ny0yLjcyOSAxLjcwNi40MDItMS4zMTggMi4wOS0xLjk5NyAyLjcyOS0xLjcwNnpNNC42ODkgNDQuOTAxYy4yMi4wNDQtMS4xNC4zMzQtMS42NTIgMS42Ni4wNzMtLjk5OCAxLjE1Ni0xLjc1OSAxLjY1Mi0xLjY2ek02LjA4OCA0Mi4yMzRjLjI3Mi4wMjYtMS4yMTEuNTc3LTEuMzI4IDIuMzM3LS4yNzgtMS4yODIuNzEyLTIuMzk2IDEuMzI4LTIuMzM3ek0yMC4zNjIgNTEuODA3Yy42MDctLjU5Mi00LjUzMiAyLjA1Ni05LjQ5Ljg1NiAyLjcxMSAxLjYzMyA4LjEyMS40ODMgOS40OS0uODU2ek0xMC42NTIgNDkuOTEyYy4yODItLjI3NS0yLjEwOS45NTctNC40MTguMzk5IDEuMjYyLjc2IDMuNzguMjI1IDQuNDE4LS4zOTl6TTYuMjY2IDQ5LjIxNGMuMTQyLS4yMjktMS4xODkuNjQ3LTIuNjg4LS4xODIuODc2Ljg5IDIuMzcuNjk3IDIuNjg4LjE4MnpNMTQuNDAyIDU3Ljk0MmMuNTUtLjI1OC0zLjE4NS0uMTg0LTUuMzMzLTMuNDM5Ljc5NyAyLjY0NiA0LjA5NCA0LjAxOSA1LjMzMyAzLjQzOXpNOC42NDYgNTMuNTA3Yy4zNjktLjE3Mi0yLjEzNy0uMTIyLTMuNTc4LTIuMzA3LjUzNSAxLjc3NiAyLjc0NiAyLjY5NyAzLjU3OCAyLjMwN3pNMzYuMTQ0IDM1Ljg0N2MtMi44MjIgNi4xMzMtMTIuNDc5IDkuNTQ5LTE0LjQ5MyAxNy4yODMgNS44MS03LjU4MiAxNS4wMDEtMTAuODQ4IDE0LjQ5My0xNy4yODN6TTIwLjc3NyAyNy4wMjRjMS4xNTQuMTg4LTUuMzU0IDIuMTItNi40MTQgOS41NTgtLjc3Ni01LjUyMSAzLjc5OS05Ljk4NCA2LjQxNC05LjU1OHpNMTEuNTk2IDI5Ljc2OWMuNzMyLjAxOS0yLjU0NiAxLjctMS4wNTYgNi4yMzItMi4wMjUtMy4yMzgtLjYwMy02LjI3NSAxLjA1Ni02LjIzMnoiLz48L3N2Zz4="
        id="vsgDyp"
      />
    </svg>
    
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="snail" />
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: To paste the entire code would be a lot of code, hence me putting into a jsfiddle, but I am happy to include it all if that is better, the base 64 image would put this onto many lines.   I will add and see if you think this is better

Comment: What mobile browser are you testing this in?

Comment: IOS safari on Iphone, it also happens on Chrome iphone