# How to make SVG larger

Tags: html, css, svg

I have some SVG images from a third party, like the below snippet.

[image]

Can I amend these to have a default larger size?  I.e. I would like these to be 256px x 256px ideally, rather than the 64px they are at the moment.

I've tried `style="transform: scale(4,4)"` but this doesn't look right, but almost what i'm after, it's just not aligned correctly.

[image]

The reason I am asking is that I am using these within an image tag, and these go blurry on Iphone when I resize them to be bigger, I am thinking this may be due to the images being stretched from their original size?  I might be wrong with this, but thought it was possible.

See this post below for the full issue of what is happening to these images when displayed on iphone.

Any help would be really appreciated.

[SVG used as image is blury on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361569/svg-used-as-image-is-blury-on-iphone)

```html
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64">
    <radialGradient id="a" cx="25.875" cy="24.504" r="31.893" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1.003 0 .963)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset=".4" stop-color="#f5000d"/>
        <stop offset=".618" stop-color="#f2010d"/>
        <stop offset=".758" stop-color="#ea040e"/>
        <stop offset=".877" stop-color="#db0a10"/>
        <stop offset=".984" stop-color="#c61213"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c21413"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M31.873 13.657C29.564 13.657 3 4.854 3 29.919 3 45.134 18.711 62 25.568 62c3.111 0 4.5-1.996 6.305-1.996 1.838 0 2.158 1.996 6.141 1.996C44.873 62 61 43.387 61 29.919c0-25.09-26.818-16.262-29.127-16.262z"/>
    <radialGradient id="b" cx="31.976" cy="15.973" r="12.221" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 .4524 0 9.758)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#b30100"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c21413" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path fill="url(#b)" d="M32 17.868c6.573 0 6.19-3.344 21.237-3.704-8.112-4.195-19.87-.507-21.364-.507-1.493 0-13.122-3.668-21.158.506 15.095.352 14.704 3.705 21.285 3.705z"/>
    <radialGradient id="c" cx="284.948" cy="-516.148" r="13.633" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0508 -.1028 -.1778 -1.0674 -373.088 -493.67)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff4f42"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff4f42" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path fill="url(#c)" d="M32.453 26.574c-1.338-8.037-8.838-13.924-16.747-13.149-7.915.773-13.245 7.914-11.907 15.951 1.34 8.038 8.84 13.925 16.752 13.15 7.913-.772 13.242-7.915 11.902-15.952z"/>
    <path fill="#449C00" d="M31.56 13.63C46.364 15.757 50.227 2.135 50.227 2.135S35.926 8.678 31.56 13.63z"/>
    <path fill="#56AB15" d="M31.56 13.63C36.563 9.247 50.227 2.135 50.227 2.135S34.22-.101 31.56 13.63z"/>
    <path fill="#785647" d="M32.67 17.868c-2.549-2.545-1.67-12.114.279-12.114 3.227 0-2.388 3.311-.279 12.114z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: the problem isn't with the svg but with how you use it. So you posted the wrong part of the code!

Comment: Ok, so do you know why when I use this in my other post that it goes blury on iphone?  I was thinking maybe it's something to do with the fact it is 64px x 64px and I am resizing to 110px

Comment: SVG images go blurry when scaled on an iPhone because they're rasterized (converted to a bitmap) and then scaled on the GPU. The viewBox solution below *should* work - if you don't scale it from its original dimensions, it shouldn't be blurry.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this is still not working for me, I still get a blury image when I base 64.  See this fiddle, showing apple converted to 256, then apple convered into base64 in image, then apple converted with shaddow.  The first two are sharp but the last is not, any ideas?  https://jsfiddle.net/u4sr1h2p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it 256px X 256px by adding viewbox settings and setting height and width to 256px.

[viewbox settings MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

```html
<svg
    viewBox="0 0 64 64"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="256px" height="256px">
    <radialGradient id="a" cx="25.875" cy="24.504" r="31.893" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1.003 0 .963)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset=".4" stop-color="#f5000d"/>
        <stop offset=".618" stop-color="#f2010d"/>
        <stop offset=".758" stop-color="#ea040e"/>
        <stop offset=".877" stop-color="#db0a10"/>
        <stop offset=".984" stop-color="#c61213"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c21413"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path fill="url(#a)" d="M31.873 13.657C29.564 13.657 3 4.854 3 29.919 3 45.134 18.711 62 25.568 62c3.111 0 4.5-1.996 6.305-1.996 1.838 0 2.158 1.996 6.141 1.996C44.873 62 61 43.387 61 29.919c0-25.09-26.818-16.262-29.127-16.262z"/>
    <radialGradient id="b" cx="31.976" cy="15.973" r="12.221" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 .4524 0 9.758)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#b30100"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c21413" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path fill="url(#b)" d="M32 17.868c6.573 0 6.19-3.344 21.237-3.704-8.112-4.195-19.87-.507-21.364-.507-1.493 0-13.122-3.668-21.158.506 15.095.352 14.704 3.705 21.285 3.705z"/>
    <radialGradient id="c" cx="284.948" cy="-516.148" r="13.633" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0508 -.1028 -.1778 -1.0674 -373.088 -493.67)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ff4f42"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ff4f42" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <path fill="url(#c)" d="M32.453 26.574c-1.338-8.037-8.838-13.924-16.747-13.149-7.915.773-13.245 7.914-11.907 15.951 1.34 8.038 8.84 13.925 16.752 13.15 7.913-.772 13.242-7.915 11.902-15.952z"/>
    <path fill="#449C00" d="M31.56 13.63C46.364 15.757 50.227 2.135 50.227 2.135S35.926 8.678 31.56 13.63z"/>
    <path fill="#56AB15" d="M31.56 13.63C36.563 9.247 50.227 2.135 50.227 2.135S34.22-.101 31.56 13.63z"/>
    <path fill="#785647" d="M32.67 17.868c-2.549-2.545-1.67-12.114.279-12.114 3.227 0-2.388 3.311-.279 12.114z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: that is great, looks exactly what I am after... time will tell if this fixes my issue, but gives me what I needed to test it out thank you very much,

Comment: Damn, didn't fix my issue, but did answer this question so thank you very much